# Android play Ooyala Video with Hook player

Tags: android, ooyala

How to play Ooyala video in hook player from a different application?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Intent launchHook = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
  (<"ooyala://pcode/embed code/null/time_in_seconds">));
    startActivity(launchHook);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Ooyala Documentation](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/concepts/hook.html) is incorrect, to create an intent to open an ooyala video in "Hook Mobile Player App" must be (without "<" and ">" characters):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
  Intent launchHook = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("ooyala://pcode/embed code/null/time_in_seconds"));
    startActivity(launchHook);
  }
}
```

where:

> - **pcode**: video player_id defined in Ooyala Backlot.
> - **embed code**: video content_id defined in Ooyala Backlot.
> - **null**:  valid token or the string "null", not required.
> - **time_in_seconds**: time in   seconds to specify the point in the video to start the app, not required.

```
Intent launchHook = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("ooyala://c9565052281a402ebf432dca9b59b2ca/45cjJ0ZDrfOUerwSu6BbChfItUCDCxZE"));
// Intent launchHook = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("ooyala://c9565052281a402ebf432dca9b59b2ca/45cjJ0ZDrfOUerwSu6BbChfItUCDCxZE/null/10"));
startActivity(launchHook);
```